# How to multiply Pandas series to represent an OR statement?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Series of booleans `series_1` and `series_2` of the same length.

How do I combine them to simulate an OR statement?
That is, if one of them is True, the equivalent element in the combined Series will be True

Comment: `series_1 | series_2`?